# Prove there exists a Turing machine $M$ that decides an infinite subset of $HALT_{TM}$.

Tags: computer-science, turing-machines

I know it exists but not sure how to prove it. I assume it needs something to make sure the elements are Halting problems, but they are undecidable so I am not sure where to start.

Comment: I assume $HALT_{TM}$ is a different notation to $HP$? The language of all TMs and their hailting inputs?

Comment: @Theorem subset should be a subset of HP I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if I understood your question correctly, finding an infinite decidable subset of $HP$ isn't that hard, since it contains many simple machines. For example, let's denote $M_0$ a TM that instantly rejects, then the language
$$L=\left \{ \left \langle M_0 \right \rangle ,x |\ x\in \Sigma^{\star}\right \} \subseteq HP$$
is decidable by checking $M$ is encoding $M_0$ and accepting/rejecting by that.